# Can you update a file in the application bundle?

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to update a file stored in an applications bundle programmatically?
Basically I want to get a remote file and overwrite one of the bundle files with it (a sqlite database in fact).

This works fine on the simulator but on the device it does not work, though it does not error either (it just doesn't seem to actually overwrite).

I know I can work around it by copying it do the user folder instead and then getting the code to check their first for the file before using the bundle one but I was interested to know whether it is possible to update a bundle file at all or am I just doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the bundle cannot be updated. Items in the bundle are packaged with the app, and the app is digitally signed so as to be able to be resold through the App Store. By changing the bundle contents, the digital signature would no longer match.

Answer (score 1):

It probably won't work because deployed app bundles are cryptographically signed by Apple (even during development). You are not allowed to change them.

Comment: I think the crypto signing is only for the compiled binary of the app and not for data files. In our work we do change files in the app folder after compilation, before creating an IPA file, and we are able to run the app successfully

Comment: @ishahak the IPA itself is signed, not individual files (though I think the binary is also individually signed). Unpack the IPA (renaming to *.zip helps), edit one of the files, repack it, and see if you can still deploy and run the app.