# I have successfully saved my plist to the documents directory! Now I can't load it back

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, plist, saving-data

This code works beautifully to save my plist to the documents directory.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.addButtonItem;
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TitleArray" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
self.titles = tmpArray;
[tmpArray release];

//TESTING NEW CODE FOR SAVING TO DOC DIR
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *docDirPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TitleArray.plist"];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: docDirPath])
{
    NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TitleArray" ofType:@"plist"];

    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath:docDirPath error:&error];

                        NSLog(@"plist is copied to Directory");
                        }
```

I have not been able to figure out how to load the plist back to the app!

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TitleArray.plist"];
NSArray * myList = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [myList mutableCopy];
self.titles = tmpArray;
[tmpArray release];
```

didn't work?

Comment: When you saved the plist you saved it in your documents directory. When you're loading it you're attempting to retrieve it from the bundle, which isn't where you saved it. Nacho's code here shows you how to retrieve it from the documents directory where you put it.

Comment: Thanks Matthew for adding this kind explanation for Andy ;)

Comment: HEY!!!! It works!! nacho4d thanks! Matthew--Thanks for spelling it out for me. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to overwrite a plist included in your app's main bundle, then you should know that it cannot be done. Take a look at this question for more details:  [Can you update a file in the application bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809482/can-you-update-a-file-in-the-application-bundle)

Comment: Hi Endemic, I wasn't trying to overwrite the plist (my poorly worded question does seem to ask that) Just wanted to retrieve the data from the doc dir. for the app to use. Seriously, what is the proper way to say this? Is it read in/write out or what? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSError *error; NSArray *paths =    
NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths    objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *docDirPath = [documentsDirectory    stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TitleArray.plist"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: docDirPath])  
{    
    docDirPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TitleArray" ofType:@"plist"];
}  
NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [[[NSMutableArray    alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: docDirPath] mutableCopy];
```